# How to cancel valueChanges in Angular and set the old value again?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, angular12

I subscribed to valueChanges of a mat-selection-list to be notified when the user selects a new list item. In some cases I ask the user if he/she really wants to select the new item via a confirmation dialog. If the user clicks "No" in this dialog, I need to cancel the selection of the new item. This is how I attempted to do this:

```
this.createForm.controls.selectionList.valueChanges.subscribe((value: number[]) => {
  const prevValue = this.createForm.controls.selectionList.value;

  if (<condition>) {
    const confirmDialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmationDialogComponent, {
      data: "Do you really want to do this?",
    });

    confirmDialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((confirmResult) => {
      if (confirmResult === true) {
        // User clicked yes, continue...
      } else {
        // User clicked no, set the previous value again...
        this.createForm.controls.selectionList.setValue(prevValue, { emitEvent: false });
      }
    });
  } else {
    // No user confirmation required, just continue...
  }
});
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work because `prevValue` seems to already be the new value when I try to set it as current value. What can I do instead to set the previous value again and basically just pretend that the user never even selected a new list item to begin with? Do I really have to cache the previous value manually, or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I think you can use the `(openedChange)` output event of `mat-select` to save the previous value when the user opens the `mat-select` dropdown and then use that value to restore to your previous value when the user does not confirm the change.</strike>

```html
 <mat-select formControlName="selectionList" (openedChange)="savePreviousValue()">
```

In your `.ts` component, create a variable that stores the previous value, if by default there is any value, set it to that value, or if be default it is empty then it is `undefined`

```js
//Can be set to default value wherever you fetch the data.
prevValue: any = undefined;
```

Then you can use this `prevValue` in your `valueChanges` subscription.

For the first time if the user does not confirm in the dialog, the prevValue will be used to set the value back to undefined, if the user confirms the dialog, then update the `prevValue` with the latest value so that it can be used the next time user does not confirm the change and so on.

Comment: It seems like `(openedChange)` does not fire in my case. I am also using a `mat-selection-list` and not a `mat-select`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: My bad I saw it as `mat-select`, I guess what you can do is create `prevValue: any` and set it's default value, if there is not value at start then just set it to null. and then use that in your `valueChanges`  to restore previous value, if the user select new value, also update that `prevValue` to the latest value.

Comment: @Chris, updated the answer with the details.

Answer (score 0):

You `subscribe()` to a form value change - why? Where is the `unsubscribe()` for this?

If you try to get `prevValue` inside the `subscribe()` then it's true, that `this.createForm.controls.selectionList.value` is already the new value.

I would bind the data and then use `ngOnChanges` to read previous and current value. We could then place the `if (<condition>)` block into `ngOnChanges`. We also then can get rid of the subscription.

If possible I would call `Event.stopPropagation()` to cancel value change event or reassign `selectionList.value` to be previousValue from simpleChange.

That or use `pairwise` and just use the previous value.

```js
observable // [1, 5, 2, 3]
  .pipe(
    pairwise() // [[1, 5], [5, 2], [2, 3]]
  )
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. I already described in my answer that I subscribed to the value change because I want to be notified when the user selects a new list item. I want this subscription to be in place for the entire lifetime of the component (dialog) in which I subscribed to the event. Do I really need to `unsubscribe` at any point here manually. Why? I also do not understand how I can get the previous and current value inside `ngOnChanges` when implementing your suggestion. Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

Probably this could be the better one. Also, Set this.prevValue after creating the form with the value you are getting initially otherwise it's [].

Try to avoid subscriptions inside the subscription for good performance.

```
private prevValue: number[] = [];

this.createForm.controls.selectionList.valueChanges.pipe(mergeMap((value: number[]) => {
    if (<condition>) {
    const confirmDialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmationDialogComponent, {
      data: "Do you really want to do this?",
    });

    return confirmDialogRef.afterClosed();
  } else {
    // No user confirmation required, just continue...
    this.prevValue = value;
    return of(undefined);
  }
})).subscribe((confirmResult) => {
    if(confirmResult != undefined) {
      if (confirmResult === true) {
        // User clicked yes, continue...
        this.prevValue = this.createForm.controls.selectionList.value;
       } else {
        // User clicked no, set the previous value again...
        this.createForm.controls.selectionList.setValue(prevValue, { emitEvent: false });
      }
  }
});
```